# Showing that $(p-2)! \equiv 1 \pmod p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, congruences

I wish to show that $(p-2)! \equiv 1 \pmod p$ for a prime $p \ge 3$ using the fact that $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$. (Deducing the latter is a later, and more advanced task.)

We have that $(p-1)(p-2)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$. We have that $(p-1) \equiv (p-1)\pmod p$, but this does not help. A weird thought along the lines of "What if I went to the other way around?" popped in my head, I wrote $(p-1) \equiv -1 \pmod p$ and $(-1)(p-2)! \equiv -1 \pmod p \implies (p-2)! \equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Much to my surprise, this was the right answer. I don't understand much of it, so this is a classic example of the right answer for the wrong reasons. If my methods are indeed valid; why do they work? If they are not; how would one normally go about solving this task, and how does one validate each step, basing ones arguments in elementary arithmetic?

Comment: Why is it a weird thought? $p - 1 \equiv -1$, so replacing $p-1$ by $-1$ is valid. Then you just multiply both sides by $-1$.

Comment: I don't get it, which is why I classified it as weird. Why is $p - 1 \equiv -1 \pmod p$? Isn't $p-1 \equiv p-1 \pmod p$?

Comment: Perhaps then you should revisit the basics of congruences and modular arithmetic. What does it mean if $a \equiv b \mod p$? Can you then prove that $p-1 \equiv -1 \mod p$?

Comment: We say that $a = b \bmod n $ if n divides $a - b$.  That's just the definition.  And $p$ does indeed divide $(p-1) - (-1)$.

Comment: @AndrewThompson , google "Wilson's Theorem"...

Comment: @DonAntonio I am to deduce that in a later task, as mentioned in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The focus of this answer would be on its explanation rather than its content.

Notice that for all prime (integers, more generally) $p \ge 3$, we have

$$(p - 1)! = (p-1)(p-2)!$$

Now, suppose $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$. This is the assumption in the question. It is the consideration we have to make. Then, taking both sides modulo $p$, we have

$$-1 \equiv (p-1)(p-2)! \pmod p$$

But $p -1$ gives a remainder of $-1$ when divided by $p$. In other words,
$$p-1\equiv -1\pmod p$$

Substituting back, we have:

$$-1\equiv -1\cdot(p-2)!\pmod p$$

Multiplying both sides by $-1$, we have

$$(p-2)! \equiv 1 \pmod p$$

What this says is that

$$(p-1)!\equiv -1 \pmod p \implies (p-2)! \equiv 1 \pmod p$$

for all prime $p \ge 3$.

Now, I believe you would have to prove $p \ge 3$ prime $\implies (p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$, to prove that the above deduction is true for $p \ge 3$ prime.

Comment: Thank you. My misunderstanding was when working with groups of the likes of $\mathbb{Z}_n$, all numbers in the interval $[0, n-1]$ "equaled themselves", that is, I did not have to find any remainder after division. Using long division on $(p-1) / p$, one may get the remainder $p-1$ if one chooses to set it equal to $0$, or a remainder of $-1$ if one sets it equal to $1$. If I understand your answer correctly, both are acceptable methods, although the latter is the one needed to solve the task.

Comment: Yes, indeed! Saying "a remainder of $-1$ after a division by $p$" is exactly the same as saying "a remainder of $p-1$ after division by $p$", because the integers modulo $p$ are closed and "wraps around" under addition (and subtraction), you could say.

Comment: Wait, is $8 \mod 16 = 8$ equivalent to saying $8 \mod 16 = -8$?

Comment: Yes it is equivalent

Answer (score 0):

For $p > 1$, the modular inverse of $(p - 1)$ is $(p - 1)$. From this, we have 
\begin{align*}
(p-1)! &\equiv_p -1\\
\Rightarrow (p-1)(p-2)! &\equiv_p -1\\
\Rightarrow (p-1)(p-1)(p-2)! &\equiv_p 1-p\\
\Rightarrow (p-2)! &\equiv_p 1 - p \equiv_p 1
\end{align*}